# I can't open Cypress on Mac: Cypress not found

Tags: javascript, npm, automated-tests, cypress

I've checked through the answers on S.O and so far none have worked for me.

I put my question in a video.  [Watch it here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dt5eg86wjlww7u4/can%27t%20open%20cypress.mp4?dl=0)

What went wrong?  It was working fine yesterday?

What I've done so far:

Re installed cypress

tried to open with : `.node_modules\.bin\cypress open`

then tried:  `npx cypress open`

Got the following message

```
No version of Cypress is installed in: /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.0/Cypress.app

Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install

----------

Cypress executable not found at: /Users/my_name/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.0/Cypress.app/Contents/MacOS/Cypress

----------

Platform: darwin (18.7.0)
Cypress Version: 3.4.0
```

Answer (score 18):

I tried the following command on my Mac and it worked:

```
npx cypress open
```

Comment: fypnlp mentioned he had tried `npx cypress open`

Comment: I first had to "npm uninstall cypress" and second "npm install cypress --save-dev". Then "npx cypress open" worked.

Answer (score 9):

`npx cypress install` worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I've been trying what you are using and experimented a bit:
`./node_modules/.bin/cypress open` works fine by me (note the forward slashes instead of the backward slashes)

`.node_modules/.bin/cypress open` does not work for me (note that this is the command you use in the video, but with the replaces slashes). In your question on stackoverflow you use an extra `/` before the node_modules, but in your video you don't.

What also should be a possibility is opening cypress via the OSX Launcher and then selecting the automation directory.

Comment: thank you for responding.   I'm a little confused by your response. Are you saying that I should go into the directory and launching it from there.  is that correct?  Also thanks for letting me know about extra slash I will remove it.

Comment: No that is not what I mean. You can launch Cypress by clicking the icon via the OSX Launcher. It will open the Cypress application, and then you need to select the directory which holds the testfiles

Answer (score 3):

This is correct and logical. In your case, on macOS, You are not installing cypress globally or adding its path in the path variable either. Therefore, if you will write `cypress run` it will not work and you would have to give the reference that from where it should pick it. i.e.
`./node_modules/.bin/cypress open`

Comment: `on macOS, You are not installing cypress globally or adding its path in the path variable either.` The same on my Ubutntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

```
npm install
```

then try to run it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear the cypress cache - for whatever reasons - you have to run the command:

```
npx cypress cache clear
```

But you must have cypress install to be able to do this command:

```
npm install cypress --save-dev
```

If you run the cache clear command then you will have to rerun the following command:

```
npx cypress install
```

You will find the details here: [clear cypress cache](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting#Clear-Cypress-cache)

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late but i think you should try this:

1 - `./node_modules/.bin/cypress install`

2 - `./node_modules/.bin/cypress open`

and then it will open cypress for you

Answer (score 0):

In mac, if you have it installed in your project, you can use something like

```
./node_modules/cypress/bin/cypress run --spec path/to/file/address
```